# swift unable to access contents of variable in IBAction. error: "Expected declaration"

Tags: swift

This program compiles fine with no errors, but crashes when i click the Button attached to IBAction check Answer.

in applicationWillResignActive(_:) i see "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"
and in my debug area, i see:
***'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Fingerz.ViewController checkAnswerButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f89e254a180'***

Can someone point me in the right direction towards what I am missing?

```
import UIKit
var num = 0
class ViewController: UIViewController

{

@IBAction func fingerGenerator(sender: AnyObject)  //request random number
{
    var randomNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
    num = randomNum
}


@IBOutlet weak var userGuess: UITextField! //user enters Guess here

@IBOutlet weak var userResult: UILabel!    //display if user is right or wrong


@IBAction func checkAnswer(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var userInput = userGuess.text.toInt()
    println(userInput)

  if num == userInput
    {
        userResult.text = "Great Job"
    }
  else
        {
         userResult.text = "Try again"
    }
}

  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  {
   super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }


}
```

Comment: You have to put `println` inside your class and, if you want, inside the `IBAction`.

Comment: Thanks CeceXX. I would like num to be a global variable, because I need to use it outside of the button function. However, if i declare num underneath ***import UIKit*** i get errors.

Comment: The code you posted needs a closing bracket to close the class.

Comment: what is the correct way to amend my code in my post ? Do i just edit my original post ? i tried putting the code here in this comment but they said it was too long. Please advise, and thank you all for the help.

Comment: Try using the code I posted in my answer and please let me know what's working and what's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted needs a closing bracket to close the class.

```
import UIKit

// You requested it to make this variable a global variable
var num = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func fingerGenerator(sendor: AnyObject)
{
    var randomNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
    num = randomNum
    println(num)
}
}
```

Comment: thanks CeceXX it works inside of the IBAction fingerGenerator. However i cant access ***num*** outside of that function.

Comment: So firstly let's just move `var num = 0 ` straight after `import UIKit`. What errors do you get? I am looking at your full code and you are still placing `println(num)` the wrong way. `println(num)` should be inside of a method or an `@IBAction`.

Comment: i get the error "Expected Declaration". Just to be clear, I am now using the code as updated in my original post.

Comment: You still haven't correctly placed `println` and the global variable in the correct place. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: re: println(num). Ah i understand you now. As you said earlier, when I put it inside the IBAction, i get no errors. That makes sense.

Comment: Glad you got it working! If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as solved by clicking to the green tick button. Thanks!

Comment: I am still unable to access the contents of num outside of the IBAction.

Comment: Please edit your question with the exact same code you are using at the moment. It'd be hard to spot the bug if you don't. Thanks!

Comment: Which `@IBaction` are you referring to?

Comment: after making your edit (declaring num after import UIKit), the only error i get now is "Cannot invoke "==" with an argument list of type '(@Ivalue Int, $T5). Swift flags "if num == Int(userGuess.text)" in checkAnswer IBAction with that error message

Comment: Yeah. In fact `userGuess.text` is not an `Int`ever. You could try declaring a variable called `userInput` and use that to compare the two values this way: `if num == userInput`

Comment: Thanks CeceXX ! The program builds with no issues now, but crashed with an error as indicated in my updated original post ! Thanks to your help, I am almost there, and learning quite a bit in the process !

Comment: Try deleting and placing the buttons again. Or go the Connections Inspector (http://www.informit.com/content/images/chap5_9780672335761/elementLinks/05fig20.jpg) and delete all the referencing outlets there for each button.

Comment: Aha, I know the feeling :) It's my pleasure!